# Non-resolvable 30 seconds freezing event id 129 (sometimes comes with disk warning id 153) source iaStorAC in new laptop

Tags: windows-10, laptop, freeze, lenovo-laptop

I have bought a new laptop (`Lenovo Thinkpad Edge 14`). I was so excited about it until I realized sometimes it freezes when I am working. It freezes for about 30 seconds and it is really annoying. And this can repeat every half hour or maybe sooner. I finally realized in `Event Viewer` that Events with IDs `129` and `153` come up when this happens. Sometimes they come alone. But whenever id `129` comes up it freezes, whether it coms with `153` or comes alone.
I have a tried a looooooot of stuff. I dug deep in the internet. The issue seems popular since there are posts talking about it since 2013. But none of the solutions worked for me. There were some stuff people suggested in `Power Options` (Turning off `Link State Power Management` in `PCI Express` and so on) I tried all of those but nothing happened. Tried installing Intel Rapid Storage Technology drivers, didn't help. Tried changing attribute values in `regedit` (HKEY_LOCALMACHINE_...) from 1 to 2 but didn't help And the worst part is some of these solutions made the issue even worse.
I uninstalled and installed different versions of `Windows 10`, `8.1`, `8` and `7` but none helped.
After a while thought there must be a problem with hardware, did a full test on hardware and the report is in this [link](https://files.fm/u/2q9wm4fzy). Also one of my friends bought the same model with me and he also has this problem so I don't think it is a hardware issue.

Please help. This is the first time in my life that I cannot solve an issue with my laptop with searching on the internet. It seems nothing works. Please, if you can help with maybe some clue even that would be really helpful.

Comment: Run the Lenovo System Update tool and update all drivers. Once done, test, and if you still have the issue, contact Lenovo Support. They will help.

Comment: I would ask for a refund, Its new, you should not have to work on a new laptop.

Comment: @Moab Guess so.

Comment: Do you guys see anything suspicious in the hardware analysis report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent back the laptop to guarantee and after a week they realized it was because of the SSD. They replaced a new SSD and now the problem is resolved.